# Insert DateTime field in Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I'm trying to insert a DateTime value in a field which is configured as Date Only in Sharepoint list.

I've tried so far:

```
item["End_x0020_Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime("11/29/2017");

item["End_x0020_Date"] = DateTime.Now;
```

I haven't received any error but the value for dates is not stored in the list. All the other fields are filled correctly. You can see the blanks below the dates I added from Sharepoint. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
 var web = context.Web;
 List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

 ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

 ListItem item = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

 item["DepartmentName"] = "IT - Networking";
 item["StartDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
 item["EndDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime("12/10/2017");
```

[image]

Comment: can you try using `item["StartDate"] = DateTime.UtcNow` and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are stored in ISO format so try this:

```
item["EndDate"] = SPUtility.CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime(DateTime.Now());
```

Comment: Thanks, How can I use that in CSOM? I couldn't find CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime

Comment: I use `datetimeobject.toISOString()`

Answer (score 1):

For CSOM use below:

```
var startdate=new Date()
var enddate=new Date("12/10/2017")
item["StartDate"]= startdate
item["EndDate"]= enddate
```